# Combine several JSON.stringify to one

Tags: javascript

How do I combine strings with JSON.stringify?

This is not working:

```
var objA = {a: 5};

var objB = {b: 6};

var str = JSON.stringify(objA) + JSON.stringify(objB);

console.log(JSON.parse(str)); //error
```

https://jsbin.com/yabacuyafe/edit?html,js,console

Expected output is: `"[{\"a\":5},{\"b\":6}]"`

Answer (score 4):

If your expected output is:

```
[{"a":5},{"b":6}]
```

Then use:

```
JSON.stringify([objA, objB])
```

If your expected output is:

```
{"a":5,"b":6}
```

Then use:

```
JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, objA, objB))
```

I do not recommend trying this with strings. Combine the objects first, then stringify.

Comment: Problem is, my array with objects is so huge. I get out of memory if I do a single JSON.stringify. So I need to chop em up and the combine them.

Comment: Perhaps JSON isn't the right tool for this job, then

Comment: I need to send data from my webworker. Serilized JSON is all I can send from there.

Comment: Can you send it in multiple parts, then combine after parsing each part?

Comment: I tried that. The Chrome tab crashed. Read it was better to make a single post.

Answer (score 2):

```
var objA = {a: 5};

var objB = {b: 6};
var combined = {
    objA: objA,
    objB: objB
}

var str = JSON.stringify(combined);

console.log(JSON.parse(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your expected output is (one object):

```
{"a":5,"b":6}

const objC = {...objA, ...objB };

var str = JSON.stringify(objC);
```